# Angular 1.5 component $router binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-component-router

I'm trying to switch a 1.5x project over to components and use the new component-router. I'm having an issue with how to programmatically access the `$router` in a couple of components that aren't sitting inside of a  directive. Basically I have header and sidebar components which need to be able to do `$router.navigvate`, but using bindings: `{$router: "<"}` gives me an undefined `$router`.

I think I might just need to restructure the app a little bit, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Currently in my Index.html I have ng-app defined on the body, and then the main app module inside of that (`<app></app>`). 
My main app component has a template with basically my "masterpage".

So app.html has a `<header>` component, `<sidebar>` component, and then `<ng-outlet>` for the main content. With UI-Router I just used the $state service in the header/sidebar controllers to find the active state or navigate to a new state.

With component-router I can't figure out how to get the $router into the header/sidebar controllers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

use $rootRouter in the controller

`function controller($rootRouter){
    $rootRouter.navigate(["someComponent"]) 
    or $rootRouter.navigateByUrl("/url")
}`